# Stripe Event - free trial expiration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I have been setting Stripe's events and wanted to setup an event when a user's free trial is close to expiration. There is a relevant event on Stripe's side which is `customer.subscription.trial_will_end`.

So I am using the stripe_event gem and already setup the following events on stripe.rb

```
StripeEvent.setup do
  subscribe 'charge.failed' do |event|
    user = User.where(stripe_customer_token: event.data.object.customer).first
    user.subscriptionstatus = "notactive"
    user.save!
    UserMailer.stripe_cancellation(user).deliver
  end

  subscribe 'charge.succeeded' do |event|
    user = User.where(stripe_customer_token: event.data.object.customer).first
    user.subscriptionstatus = "active"
    user.save!
    UserMailer.invoice_mail.deliver
  end
end
```

I was wondering how this `customer.subscription.trial_will_end` will be setup. Is it described as: `subscribe 'trial_will_end'` or `customer 'subscription.trial_will_end`' or...? How do I figure this out? The two previous one I created them with a clue I had from another developer, here in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stripe_event` uses the actual event name (or optionally its higher-level namespace, if you want to perform the same action on a whole class of events).

To handle `customer.subscription.trial_will_end` events, subscribe to them just as you have with  your existing event types:

```
  subscribe 'customer.subscription.trial_will_end' do |event|
    # do stuff
  end
```